# Добавление данных в БД через форму

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, форма

Заношу данные в БД через форму. Т.е. в одном файле создаю форму для ввода,
и методом $_POST отправляю в другой файл, где находится код для вставки введенных данных в БД. Ругается как раз на ту самую главную строчку, которая за вставку и отвечает.

```
 $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO firma ('name','surname','doljnost') VALUES ('$name','$surname','$doljnost')");
```

Пишет: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\mysql_insert2.php on line 38`

Вот такую "штуку" накарябала в файле, которые отправляет данные в БД.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'alex', '12345', 'firstbd');

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* изменение набора символов на utf8 */
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
}

if(isset($_POST['surname']))
{
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
}

if(isset($_POST['doljnost']))
{
$doljnost = $_POST['doljnost'];
}

$result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO firma ('name','surname','doljnost') VALUES ('$name','$surname','$doljnost')");

if ($result==true)
{
echo "<br>Информация в базу добавлена успешно.";
}
else echo "<br>Информация в базу не добавлена.";

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Кстати, я еще вот так пробовала писать:
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO firma ('name','surname','doljnost') VALUES ('Андрей','Андреев','Водитель')");
 
$myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($myrow == true)
{
echo "Информация в Базу Данных успешно добавлена!";
}
else echo "Информация в Базу Данных НЕ добавлена!";

Comment: @elenavictory, в этом нет необходимости. Для ``insert`` вернется ``boolean``

Comment: вместо `mysqli` лучше сразу [разбираться](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) с `PDO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот документация: [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php). В процедурном стиле функция принимает два параметра: идентификатор соединения и запрос.

Таким образом, стоит написать так:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO firma (`name`,`surname`,`doljnost`) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$doljnost')";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // ключевой момент - первый параметр
```

*Что входящие данные нельзя подставлять без обработки вы, надеюсь, знаете.*

Cтолбцы БД выделяются [обратным](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Машинописный_обратный_апостроф), а не [обычным](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Машинописный_апостроф) апострофом, т.е. ` вместо '

Чтобы узнать, что случилось используйте [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Вместо "Информация в базу не добавлена" напишите:

```
echo mysqli_error($link);
```

Comment: @xEdelweiss, вы даже не представляете, как долго я читала этот мануал, прежде, чем обратилась сюда за помощью...
Так, как написали вы, я уже пробовала писать.
Ошибки тогда не выдает. Но и данные не добавляет.
Выходит мое сообщение: "Информация в базу не добавлена."

Comment: @elenavictory, я обновил ответ. Напишите: ``(`name`,`surname`,`doljnost`)`` вместо ``('name','surname','doljnost')``

Comment: @xEdelweiss, нет... не работает. Что значит, нельзя данные подставлять без обработки? То, что я вот так делала: if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
}
Это не называется обработкой?

Comment: @elenavictory, вам надо узнать конкретную ошибку (``mysqli_error``). Смотрите в ответе. 

По поводу данных - обработкой, конечно, но я имел ввиду валидацию этих данных, т.к. там может быть что угодно. Читайте про SQL-инъекции.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Разобралась!:)

Comment: Замечательно :)

Comment: @elenavictory читайте про bind_param и prepare

Answer (score 2):

А не должно быть так?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO firma ('name','surname','doljnost') VALUES ('".$name."','".$surname."','".$doljnost."')"); // обновил! Теперь вставятся :)
```

Вроде ж как нужно добавить ссылку на коннект к бд... или ошибаюсь?

//ps пока отвечал эдельвейс сделал это быстрее :(

Comment: @Shrek, и так я тоже пробовала писать. Тоже не помогает...
Так же - нет ошибок, но данные в БД не попадают.

Comment: Ссылку можно упускать если у вас одно единственное соединение в базу.